# Clickable area with position absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs my first div contains the links with image  and my second div with a `position:absolute` my absolute area is not clikable how can I make it clikable ?

can I make clickable empty are of my position:absolute ?

here you are this is my code and I'm using bootstrap

```css
.item img{
  width:100%;
  height:700px !important;
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.booking-form {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 45px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.tab-system .tab-content{
  padding:12px;
  background:#FFF;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
}
.carousel-control{    
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
    top: 50%;
     margin-top: -10px; 
     display: inline-block; 
}
.carousel-control.right {
       right: 10%;

}
.carousel-control.left {
     left: 10%;
}
```

```html
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  
  <div class="booking-form">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="tab-system">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam commodi accusantium, voluptas quisquam obcaecati labore odit tenetur amet ex libero iste quam, nostrum temporibus architecto mollitia ipsum dignissimos non similique.</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><!-- this is the booking form-->
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/40797/wild-flowers-flowers-plant-macro-40797.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3247/nature-forest-industry-rails.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Do you want something like `pointer-events: none;`? Use it in your `.booking-form`. To get your tabs also working use `.nav-tabs { pointer-events: visible; }`.

Comment: you want to click on the tab body and trigger the slider slide?

Comment: my image has a href I want to make it clickable but in position area my image is unclickable I want to clickable on position area too

Comment: demo: http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/dWVzeb

Comment: for example left  and right of the my tab is not clickable it must be clickable

Comment: @Huelfe does ie support this css property ?

Comment: Yes. See [https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events](https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you mean, first you have to add `pointer-events: none;` property for your parents element and you have to add `pointer-events: visible;` property for your child element.

now it's working

```css
.item img{
  width:100%;
  height:700px !important;
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.booking-form {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 45px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tab-system{
   pointer-events: visible; 
}

.tab-system .tab-content{
  padding:12px;
  background:#FFF;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
}
.carousel-control{    
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
    top: 50%;
     margin-top: -10px; 
     display: inline-block; 
}
.carousel-control.right {
       right: 10%;

}
.carousel-control.left {
     left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  
  <div class="booking-form">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="tab-system">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam commodi accusantium, voluptas quisquam obcaecati labore odit tenetur amet ex libero iste quam, nostrum temporibus architecto mollitia ipsum dignissimos non similique.</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><!-- this is the booking form-->
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/40797/wild-flowers-flowers-plant-macro-40797.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3247/nature-forest-industry-rails.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```